# Understanding metadata values from SQL Server query

Tags: sql-server

I just run a `sqlsrv_field_metadata` on my table like so:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM vw_Persons";

$stmt = sqlsrv_query($gaSql['link'], $query) or die("<pre>" . print_r(sqlsrv_errors()) . "<br><br>$query</pre>");
    $obj = sqlsrv_fetch_object( $result );

    foreach( sqlsrv_field_metadata( $stmt ) as $fieldMetadata ) {
            foreach( $fieldMetadata as $name => $value) {
                     echo "$name: $value<br />";
                }
                 echo "<br />";
            }
```

on 1 of the columns, I got this data:

```
Name: isActive
Type: -7
Size:
Precision: 1
Scale:
Nullable: 0
```

Does anyone knows what type=-7 stands for? I know that's the numeric value for the SQL type - but what type would that be?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

found the answer

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/numeric-types.html
bit     SQL_BIT (-7)

it means is a data type bit